# AWS RDS slow when CPU usage below Baseline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS **db.t3.micro** instance. Its baseline performance is 20%. When ever my RDS CPU usage spike goes **above 20%**, my API calls becomes slow for 1 to 2 minutes. After that API calls are working fine.
I have Good amount of CPU Credits.
Why I am getting this 1 to 2 minutes lag?

I am attaching the screenshots of **CPU Usage, CPU credits usage & CPU credit balance** at the time **Oct 21, 2021 18:25 PM UTC+5.30**
Please have a look at the below screenshots.

Time is missing when i take screenshots with laptop. That's why I took the photos with mobile.
[image: CPU Usage]
[image: CPU Credit Usage]
[image: CPU Credits Balance]

What Should I do to avoid this lag with RDS?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is "high CPU makes my queries slow" and not "my slow queries spike my CPU"?

Comment: Yes, I noted the exact time when queries becomes slow. Queries are same all the time. So I don't think "my slow queries spike my CPU". It should be "high CPU makes my queries slow".

Comment: Aside from CPU, can you check the IOPS as well? Both write and read. Sometimes bottleneck in IOPS can cause a spike in CPU.

Comment: Read IOPS are 2300-2400, but I don't know the limit of Read IOPS for db.t3.micro.
Write IOPS are below 10.

Comment: I'd check this with AWS support. You can also try to create a reduced test case. That will help you to debug this.